# table row background image

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we solve the table row background image problem, in chrome, in multi celled tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997405/can-we-solve-the-table-row-background-image-problem-in-chrome-in-multi-celled)

I'm trying to have one image as the background for the first row. The problem is that the background gets applied to each cell separately, not as a whole. Is there a way around it?

http://jsfiddle.net/bumpy009/c3txj/

Result should look something like this:

[image]

EDIT: The problem appears only in Safari, Opera and chrome. Didn't check IE yet.

Comment: take a look at [this answer to a post on the subject](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3052686/547020). there are many out there (on stackoverflow) but this one looks promising.

Comment: In your JS Fiddle, with Firefox/Chrome, it *does* look like that. What browser are you using?

Comment: @DavidThomas Interesting... I use Safari.

Comment: @DavidThomas not for me.. IE and FF it works... but in Chrome it fails, too!

Comment: For future readers: [at this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312482/background-image-on-tr) is solution for your problem as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it across each row, why not make it the table background instead and repeat it in the y-axis?

```
table {
    width: 300px;
    background-image: url('mypic.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

BTW I tested your code with IE9, FF12 - those are showing the image once per row. But Chrome 15 & Safari 5 is repeating it for each td.

## Edit

Since you only wanted it in the first-row, you should use background-position to make sure the image stays at the top of the table (that's usually where the first row is, right? :P)

```
table {
    width: 300px;
    background-image: url('mypic.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
}
```

Comment: I only want the background for the first row.

Comment: @domino only the first row?! Lemme update my answer...

Comment: http://browsershots.org/http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/c3txj/10/show/ this expires in half hour, but you can always rerun the tool

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about your cell widths (are they variable?), but table elements render as such. For getting the desired effect, they need to be displayed as something else:

```
tr {display: block;}
td, th {display: inline-block; background: transparent;}
```

You will notice, that now you need to set widths for td and th elements, though.

See [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/c3txj/11/).

Comment: Thanks, now I've got two working solutions.