# CSS to set the background color for just a percentage of the width of a table row

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a basic table with two columns: name and value. I'd like to shade each row in the table an appropriate percentage of the width based on the size of the value (to essentially create a sideways histogram!). I can write code to calculate the appropriate percentage to set, but I can't figure out the CSS to actually shade each row appropriately. It seems like the whole row can be shaded, but not a percentage. Is that true?

For what it's worth, I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and I can use jQuery too if need be. This is only running on Chrome so CSS3 & Webkit only is fine! Here's the HTML:

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody class="lead">              
    <tr> 
      <td>
        Joe
      </td>
      <td>
        10
      </td>
    </tr>              
    <tr> 
      <td>
        Jane
      </td>
      <td>
        20 
      </td>
    </tr>              
    <tr> 
      <td>
        Jim
      </td>
      <td>
        2
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any tips on how to make this happen? Hope this question makes sense.

Comment: Would it work if the solution is **CSS3**-specific?

Comment: You should look at gradients, Im not sure exactly how, but I know that in gradients you can do this, and then use jquery to modify the .attr()

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could use linear-gradients.

If the percentage is 40%:

```
table{
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(40%,#F00), color-stop(40%,#00F));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left center, #F00 40%, #00F 40%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #F00 40%, #00F 40%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #F00 40%, #00F 40%);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uuR2L/263/)

So, in JavaScript,

```
var percentage=40,
    col1="#F00",
    col2="#00F";
var t=document.getElementById('table');
t.style.background = "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top,right top, color-stop("+percentage+"%,"+col1+"), color-stop("+percentage+"%,"+col2+"))";
t.style.background = "-moz-linear-gradient(left center,"+col1+" "+percentage+"%, "+col2+" "+percentage+"%)";
t.style.background = "-o-linear-gradient(left,"+col1+" "+percentage+"%, "+col2+" "+percentage+"%)";
t.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right,"+col1+" "+percentage+"%, "+col2+" "+percentage+"%)";
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uuR2L/264/)

---

If you want to apply this to each row differently:

```
var col1="#F00",
    col2="#00F";
var els=document.getElementById('table').getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (var i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
    var percentage = Number(els[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[1].firstChild.nodeValue);
    els[i].style.background = "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top,right top, color-stop("+percentage+"%,"+col1+"), color-stop("+percentage+"%,"+col2+"))";
    els[i].style.background = "-moz-linear-gradient(left center,"+col1+" "+percentage+"%, "+col2+" "+percentage+"%)" ;
    els[i].style.background = "-o-linear-gradient(left,"+col1+" "+percentage+"%, "+col2+" "+percentage+"%)";
    els[i].style.background = "linear-gradient(to right,"+col1+" "+percentage+"%, "+col2+" "+percentage+"%)" ;
}
```

The problem is that setting the background to the `tr` works well on Firefox and Opera, but on Chrome the gradient is applied to each cell.

This problem can be fixed adding this code (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10515894):

```css
#table td {display: inline-block;}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uuR2L/8/)

Comment: thanks! however, this shades the entire table. each row needs a different percentage with shaded. how can i adapt this code to do that?

Comment: @tonic, just select a `tr` instead of the whole table.

Comment: thanks for the edit @oriol! in the edit you added, i noticed the whole row isn't shaded in the jsfiddle, but just the name cells. is it possible to shade the entire row a certain percent?

Comment: @tonic Check my answer for a non-gradient solution.

Comment: I'm applying this to an existing table, but when I get to the four lines that begin with els[i].style.background part, IE keeps saying it's an "Invalid Argument". Firefox and Chrome don't seem to have a problem with it (as expected). Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 12):

No need to use gradients. First, create a simple image file with the color that you want to shade your row with. In my case, I created a `.png` which is fully colored black (`black.png` in the example below). Now, just use the `background-image` and `background-size` properties to color the appropriate part of the row.

Example, HTML:

```
<table cellspacing = "0px">
    <tr class = "row"><td>Hello Hello</td><td>Bye Bye</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    background-color: white; /*fallback color*/
    background-image: url(black.png);
    background-size: 75% 100%; /*your percentage is the first one (width), second one (100%) is for height*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: rgb(0, 140, 200);
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Here's a simple snippet on how to automate this for your example:

```
var tbl = document.getElementsByClassName("table")[0];
var rws = tbl.rows;
for(var i = 0; i < rws.length; i ++) {
    var percentage = parseInt(rws[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1].innerHTML, 10);
    rws[i].style.backgroundImage = "black.png";
    rws[i].style.backgroundSize = percentage + "%" + " 100%";
    rws[i].style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
    rws[i].style.color = "rgb(0, 140, 200)";
}
```

Little demo: [percentage width bg color (non-gradient based)](http://jsfiddle.net/U6LWV/34/).

I hope that helped!

Comment: this is really cool. for some reason though, each cell is shaded 75% of the way (in both columns). unlike your screenshot, it's not spanning the entire width. i'll continue to poke around though since your example seems to work !

Comment: @tonic That's a Chrome's bug which I fixed in the last edit of my answer.

Comment: @tonic You need to add `position: relative; display: block;` to the rows for this to work with Chrome. This is a known issue when using `background-image`. Refer to my demo, which works on Chrome, too.

Comment: @tonic note also that I had a typo in my JavaScript code. Check now for a working demo and corrected code.

Comment: ah, chrome bug ! thanks ! both your solution + oriol should work!

Comment: for the jsfiddle, here is a working black pixel: http://www.delhisweetcentre.co.uk/pics/black-pixel.jpg

Comment: This is a better solution because linear-gradient css isn't stabilised yet. +1