# How to set just a percentage of a color in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have some GUI guidelines where these color are specified:

```
text-color: #000 87%
background-color of the container: #000 20%
```

How can I apply those requirements in CSS?

I have read this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12021283

But it didn't help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The above answer is the correct one if you're looking for colors with a bit of transparency. This is a really great introduction to rgba: http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/ Black is pretty easy to convert: #000 >> rgba( 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ) This is a great tool if you have other hex values you need to convert: http://www.hexcolortool.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [RBGA](http://www.css3.info/preview/rgba/):

> text-color: #000 87%

would translate to:

> color: RGBA(0,0,0,.87)

This is assuming they are asking for a percentage of opacity.

If, on the other hand, they are asking for a tint, that's a bit more difficult to handle. Not so much with black (as that translates to varying shades of gray) but mostly impossible with color as it would depend on which color model you are using to calculate the tint value. So, if they *are* asking for a completely opaque tint, tell whoever spec'd out the colors that they need to give you precise RGB or Hex values.

Answer (score 0):

You need first to convert hex code to rgb by using the tool below ...

[hex to rgb](http://colorhex.info)

and then using this code in css color: rgba(r,g,b,transparent value);

example for black color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 87);

Answer (score 0):

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-hex-code-colors-alpha-values

Use full color code.
For example: `text-color: #ffffff87`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34811115)