# JSF-<table> tag does not apply the backgroundimage

Tags: html, css, jsf-2, primefaces

My questions is similar to the question given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514900/table-row-background-image)

I am trying to add an background image to the `<table>` component which is inside an `<p:panel>`

I tried lot of soluitons including the one given below but no luck.The background image is not applied in the table.

```
table {
    width: 300px;
    background-image: url('mypic.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
}
```

In my workspace, the image that I am trying to provide in the  background is located under 
**C:\workspaces\Project\WebContent\resources\images\mylogo.jpg**

Please let me know how to add background image to a `<table>` which is inside an `<p:panel>` in XHTML file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**In pure CSS,**

if you declare :

```
background-image: url('mypic.png');
```

your image must be relative to your CSS file.
It can only work if the CSS file and the image are in the same folder.

**In JSF2,**

CSS and resources are handled by the JSF layer for convenience.
Resources must be placed in the "WebContent/resources" folder and accessed with EL:

```
background-image: url(#{resource['images:mypic.png']});
```

Comment: @Stephane.Thanks a lot for your suggestions.I resolved the issue by adding <table width="100%" height="420px"  style="border: double 3px gray; margin-top: 5px;background-image: url('../resources/images/logo.jpg');background-repeat: no-

repeat;">

Answer (score -1):

I resolved the above issue by adding the  following attributes to the `<table>` tag

```
<table width="100%" height="420px" style="border: double 3px gray; margin-top: 5px;background-image: url('../resources/images/logo.jpg');background-repeat: no- repeat;">
```