# Why is this table row background image disappearing behind the table cell?

Tags: html, css

This has me stumped. I'm setting a background image on a tr. For some reason it disappears at the 4th column. Even stranger, the column it disappears behind depends on the width of the table.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something dead obvious.

**Edit**: this does not happen with `background-repeat: repeat;`.
**Edit2**: added a 100% width sample to demonstrate that this has nothing to do with the actual table width.
**Edit3**: Just checked in a couple of browsers. This only happens in Chrome and Opera. Firefox and Edge are unaffected. So Bug?

Can anybody explain this?

[image: screenshot of an html table with background loading image]

```css
.data-table {
  width: 600px;
}

tr.ticket-rows {
  background-image: url('https://media.tenor.com/images/6b7cfb462a7f171e6b1aca63fd5c0173/tenor.gif');
  background-position: 200px -50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

tr, td {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 100px
}
```

```html
<table class="data-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="ticket-rows">
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="on"></td>
      <td><a href="http://example.com/3589">3589</a></td>
      <td>John Smith</td>
      <td>New</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Medium</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ticket-rows">
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="on"></td>
      <td><a href="http://example.com/3589">3589</a></td>
      <td>John Smith</td>
      <td>New</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Medium</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```css
.data-table {
  width: 100%;
}

tr.ticket-rows {
  background-image: url('https://media.tenor.com/images/6b7cfb462a7f171e6b1aca63fd5c0173/tenor.gif');
  background-position: 300px -50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

tr, td {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 100px
}
```

```html
<table class="data-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="ticket-rows">
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="on"></td>
      <td><a href="http://example.com/3589">3589</a></td>
      <td>John Smith</td>
      <td>New</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Medium</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ticket-rows">
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="on"></td>
      <td><a href="http://example.com/3589">3589</a></td>
      <td>John Smith</td>
      <td>New</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Medium</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://codepen.io/franatec/pen/yLeeKzr?editors=1100

Comment: Weird, this was new to me as well. Here are some possible solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312482/background-image-on-tr

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @Ted Whitehead, comment on that post says "W3C says you cannot place a background image on a <TR> tag" which may explain it, although I haven't been able to find an actual reference at w3schools or Mozilla docs. I may consider the div hack. Just wish I understood where this behavior is coming from.

Comment: @j08691, I'm expecting the background image to be visible regardless of it's position in the row.

Comment: But you're limiting the width of the table and the cell isn't wide enough to display it, so it gets cut off

Comment: @j08691, check again. That's not what's happening at all. At 100% width it's still cropped. `background-repeat` is not cropped but fills the entire width. After some digging I'm seeing this in Chrome and Opera only, not FF or Edge, so I'm guessing it's a bug.

Comment: @TedWhitehead, this appears to be a bug. I've submitted a report to chromium.org.

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right you want an image behind your tr, you can add `background-size: cover` to fix this issues but it looks weird!

```css
.data-table {
  width: 600px;
}

tr.ticket-rows {
  background-image: url('https://media.tenor.com/images/6b7cfb462a7f171e6b1aca63fd5c0173/tenor.gif');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

tr, td {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table class="data-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="ticket-rows">
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="on"></td>
      <td><a href="http://example.com/3589">3589</a></td>
      <td>John Smith</td>
      <td>New</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Medium</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ticket-rows">
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="on"></td>
      <td><a href="http://example.com/3589">3589</a></td>
      <td>John Smith</td>
      <td>New</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Medium</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Chromium and has been added to the issue list. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1093390#c5

@AliKianoor provides a possible, but not perfect workaround. An alternative workaround would be do use a full size image so `background-repeat: repeat` can be used without side effects. Neither of these are optimal.