# Image as background not working in Chrome and Safari

Tags: css

I am using `jQuery.DataTables` to display my data and everything seems to be working fine and i use `DT_RowClass` parameter in `DataTables` to assign class to everyrow in my DataTable.

Problem I am facing is, the class I am assigning to row has an background-image as property like:
`.testClass { background: url("img/testClass.png") no-repeat 30px top; }`

`30px and top` is used as I want image to appear bit right and at top. Now in `Firefox and IE`, I get 1 image in every row (as expected) but in `Chrome and Safari`, I get multiple images (1 in every column, 30px right in column and at top). Looks like, `Chrome and Safari` are applying class to every `td` whereas i have given it as `tr` level.

I have inspected CSS and their is no class at `td` level.

Anyone had this problem with these browser.

**EDIT**
My HTML looks like
    `<table>
    <tr id="xyz" class="test">
    <td>Test Columns1</td>
    <td>Test Columns2</td>
    <td>Test Columns2</td>
    </tr>
    </table>`

Apologies, dont know how to format this properly

Comment: @BarbaraLaird: you are pointing me to my question??

Comment: oops wrong link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997405/can-we-solve-the-table-row-background-image-problem-in-chrome-in-multi-celled

Comment: @BarbaraLaird: The link you have given does depict the same problem but as I am using ````DataTables```` to display data, I dont have that much control on ````td````